# d3 updates new elements transition in

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a barchart that I am updating perfectly fine like this:

```
var bar=chart.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data);
  bar.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { if(scale(d.values.total)<0){return width/2+widthDateLabel;}else{return width/2-scale(d.values.total)-widthDateLabel;}})
          .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(scale(d.values.total)); })
          .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
          .attr("fill", function(d) { if(scale(d.values.total)<0){ return "DeepPink"}else{return "MediumSeaGreen"}})
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });
  bar.exit()
    .transition().duration(750)
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + (i + 1) * barHeight + ")"; })
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove();
  bar
    .transition().duration(750)
      .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
      .attr("x", function(d) { if(scale(d.values.total)<0){return width/2+widthDateLabel;}else{return width/2-scale(d.values.total)-widthDateLabel;}})
      .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(scale(d.values.total)); })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { if(scale(d.values.total)<0){ return "DeepPink"}else{return "MediumSeaGreen"}})
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });
```

update itself works perfectly fine. transition also. Just when there are new bars added they immediately appear in the place where it should appear and do not have any transition (e.g., opacity change, or delay before it appears). Is there any way I can differentiate between new data transition and updating data transition? It looks pretty ugly like this and I cannot believe that this is how d3 does things. So there must be a workaround for this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would set the initial opacity to 0, then when they appear just update that opacity to transition from 0 to 1. Similar to what you are doing now, just opposite

Comment: Remove this line when you append the rect 
  `.attr("height", barHeight - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @thisOneGuy who gave the hint about opacity. I started understanding that the "setup" means the inital before the transition, but it only affects the newly added elements in the update. so here is my solution (I went for opacity change + new elements coming from bottom):

```
var bar=chart.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data);
  bar.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { if(scale(d.values.total)<0){return width/2+widthDateLabel;}else{return width/2-scale(d.values.total)-widthDateLabel;}})
          .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(scale(d.values.total)); })
          .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
          .attr("opacity", 0)
          .attr("fill", function(d) { if(scale(d.values.total)<0){ return "DeepPink"}else{return "MediumSeaGreen"}})
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + (i+Math.abs(monthLengthDiff)) * (barHeight) + ")"; });
  bar.exit()
    .transition().duration(750)
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + (i + 1) * barHeight + ")"; })
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove();
  bar
    .transition().duration(750)
      .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
      .attr("x", function(d) { if(scale(d.values.total)<0){return width/2+widthDateLabel;}else{return width/2-scale(d.values.total)-widthDateLabel;}})
      .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(scale(d.values.total)); })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { if(scale(d.values.total)<0){ return "DeepPink"}else{return "MediumSeaGreen"}})
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; })
      .attr("opacity", 1)
```